# Eclipse juno android xml editor missing buttons

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-xml, eclipse-juno

I decided lately to start playing arround with some Android programming and I have a very wierd problem that I can not specify if it is caused by the version of Eclipse that I use (aka Juno). More specifically, when I open let's say the AndroidManifest.xml on eclipse Indigo at the bottom there are 5 buttons, Manifest, Application, Permission, Instrumentation and AndroidManifest.xml.

Now when I open this file on eclipse Juno (forgot to mention that I use the latest Android sdk tools) there are no such buttons at the bottom and I simply can't move to another aspect/view. I don't know if it is a version specific problem with Juno, but since I find it kinda annoying and I prefer mostly to work on Juno.

I tried to search arround the net a bit and couldn't find anything, also I could't find an option in Eclipse that could (perhaps) disable/enable such a feature. Also, i 'd like to mention that my OS is ubuntu 12.04 lts 32 bit.

Any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: Use intellij IDEA http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/ :D

Answer (score 0):

Try open these with right click on an xml file, then use Open With -> Android XML Common Editor.

Comment: Tried that already (my bad that i forgot to mention it). I pretty much already tried to use Open With -> all the options available but that didn't solve it.

Comment: Dunno, try to remove eclipse, delete all files (of eclipse, obv) and reinstall it.